# ipplan - update on info field in ipaddradd

Tags: php, mysql

I am using ipplan v4.92a, and I am trying to write directly into the ipplan mysql database from a script that extracts information from various devices.
Most of this info should go into ipaddradd.info, which should be fine due to its datatype.

Now, even though the string-content of the info-field looks like it is composed of some variables plus the actual string, I thought that I’d figured out what it means.

e.g.:
a:1:{s:4:"info";s:50:"whatever
info
”;}

Here, 50 seems to be the stringlength of what you actually want to see in the “Additional information” field in the webinterface. The other values never change throughout the table, so I assumed it to be save to be left aside and just copy them in.

I’d expect to see just that on the website:

```
---Additional information-----------
<AUTOINSERT-START>whatever
info
<AUTOINSERT-END>
--------------------------------
```

However, when I do an update on the table:

```
update ipaddradd set info='a:1:{s:4:"info";s:50:" whatever
info
";}' where ipaddr=176356937 and baseindex=62
```

then what I actually see on the webinterface is this:

```
---Additional information-----------
a:1:{s:4:"info";s:50:" <AUTOINSERT-START>whatever
info
<AUTOINSERT-END>";}
--------------------------------
```

When I copy the string for the actual information, paste it into the Additional-information field on the webinterface and hit submit, the string in the value-field in the database stays exactly the same. Only the webinterface now supresses the prefix/suffix ('a:1:{s:4:"info";s:50:") as expected and only shows the info I am interested in.

I couldn’t find any triggers on the table, neither could I see any functions pr procedures, so I can’t quite figure how this happens.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Matt

Comment: Have you found the solution already?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE ipaddradd 
SET info = "a:1:{s:4:'info';s:50:'whatever info ';}"
WHERE ipaddr = 176356937 
AND baseindex = 62
```

Als make sure `ipaddr` and `baseindex` are Int in your database.
If they are not, Try:

```
UPDATE ipaddradd 
SET info = "a:1:{s:4:'info';s:50:'whatever info ';}"
WHERE ipaddr = '176356937' 
AND baseindex = '62'
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got that working - thanks Nick for posting. This pointed me into the right direction, will vote you up as soon as I have enough points. There were problems in my calculation of the string-length.

```
update ipaddradd set info='a:1:{s:4:"info";s:50:"<AUTOINSERT-START>whatever
info
<AUTOINSERT-END>";}' where ipaddr=176356937 and baseindex=62
```

I mentioned that in "...s:50", the 50 goes for the stringlength of the information. I fixed the problem by correctly calculating the stringlength:

```
update ipaddradd set info='a:1:{s:4:"info";s:48:"<AUTOINSERT-START>whatever
info
<AUTOINSERT-END>";}' where ipaddr=176356937 and baseindex=62
```

That does the trick.

Obviously, ipplan checks if the stringlength is correct and screw

Thanks,
Matt